# Как вызвать свой конструктор Фрагмента из preference-headers

Tags: android, java

Обычно в примерах советуют делать экран настроек так:
Создать файл **pref_headers.xml** примерно такого содержания:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >      
   <header 
       android:fragment="ru.my.proj.MActivity$PrefFragment1"
       android:title="@string/pref_header_1" />
   <header 
       android:fragment="ru.my.proj.MActivity$PrefFragment2"
       android:title="@string/pref_header_2" />
</preference-headers>
```

И для каждой категории настроек создавать свой **Fragment** вида:

```
public static class PrefFragment1 extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_1);
    }
}
```

Но если таких категорий много, то не лучше ли описать один **Fragment** со своим конструктором:

```
public static class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    private int resource;

    public PrefFragment(int res) {
        resource = res;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(resource);
    }
}
```

Но только как теперь из **pref_headers.xml** вызвать описанный выше конструктор?

Answer (score 2):

Всё-таки нашел ответ на вопрос в официальной документации в середине [этого документа](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).
Если коротко, то к **header** можно добавить элемент **extra**, который представляет из себя пару ключ-значение:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >      
   <header 
      android:fragment="ru.my.proj.MActivity$PrefFragment1"
      android:title="@string/pref_header_1" >
      <extra android:name="category" android:value="Category1"/>
   </header>
   <header 
      android:fragment="ru.my.proj.MActivity$PrefFragment2"
      android:title="@string/pref_header_2" >
      <extra android:name="category" android:value="Category2"/>
   </header>
</preference-headers>
```

А в **PrefFragment** можно проверить его методом **getArguments()**:

```
public static class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String settings = getArguments().getString("category");
        if ("Category1".equals(settings)) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_1);
        } else if ("Category2".equals(settings)) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_2);
        }

    }
}
```

Оказалось достаточно просто!